# How to load an arbitrary image so that the result has a specific ColorModel in Java?

Tags: java, image, colors, textures

In my application, I need to load arbitrary images in PNG format into memory. The raw image data is required to be stored with a specific color model in memory.

Is there an efficient (low-overhead, capable of being executed concurrently by multiple threads) method of performing the conversion from input color model to the desired one?

---

In my case, I have to make sure that the end result has an 8-bit-per-channel RGBA memory layout. I want to load images using several threads, each thread processing one image at a time.

Loading a indexed PNG with `ImageIO.read` yields an indexed memory layout, which I need to somehow convert. Using a `Graphics2D` object seems to bear a huge overhead and may not be capable of concurrency on some systems (please correct me if I'm wrong). I have not been able to find any method in `BufferedImage`, `WritableRaster` or any other related class that would perform the conversion for arbitrary `ColorModel`s.

I have also considered using [STB](https://github.com/nothings/stb), but as STB uses global variables to hold state internally it is not thread-safe.

Comment: It is certainly capable of concurrency, as long as each image is handled by no more than one thread.  I am not aware of any API that reads directly into a different ColorModel.

Comment: @VGR, are you speaking about Graphics or STB? As for Graphics, I think the language of the java.awt package Javadocs mentions that the operations can be hardware-accelerated, meaning OpenGL or something similar may get involved, requiring synchronization at library level, e.g. Graphics.drawImage may block.

Comment: I was talking about Graphics.  AWT *Components* need to be used in a single thread (the AWT event dispatch thread), but I don’t think offscreen graphics operations are subject to that restriction.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll use that approach in the meanwhile then. Do you know where I could ask to get a more definitive answer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is the best source I can think of.  You may have to wait a day or two to get useful answers, if in fact there is an answer other than drawing onto a second image.